# is there a way to escape spaces for the "DIR" command

Tags: windows, go, cmd

I know that `dir` requires you to double-quote a directory name that has spaces, but I'm forced to use `cmd /C` which doesn't respect double-quotes

now to list a directory that has a space in its name seems impossible, whereas the `CD` commands doesn't care at all about spaces, executing `> CD New folder` will move you to `New folder` without any issues.

**EDIT**

I'm trying to call it from a `Go` program

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

// this function wraps up `exec.Command`
func CommandRunner(cmd string) ([]byte, error) {
    // make stdout and stderr buffers to save the output to
    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
    // make up the command
    command := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", cmd)
    // set stdout and stderr to the command's stdout and stderr
    command.Stdout = &stdout
    command.Stderr = &stderr

    // start the command and watch for errors
    if err := command.Start(); err != nil {
        // return the err and stderr
        return stderr.Bytes(), err
    }
    // wait for the command to finish
    if err := command.Wait(); err != nil {
        // return the err and stderr
        return stderr.Bytes(), err
    }

    return stdout.Bytes(), nil
}

func main() {
    cmd := `dir "C:\Users\pyed\Desktop\new folder"`
    out, _ := CommandRunner(cmd)
    fmt.Println(string(out))

}
```

it will return `the filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect`, any commands without double-quotes will work just fine.

execute `cmd /?` and read the section that starts with `If /C or /K...` that what made me say `cmd /C` doesn't allow double-quotes

Comment: Are you sure that `cmd /c dir "New Folder"` will not work?

Comment: You can use spaces in commands. I just tested with this full command prompt: `C:\Windows\System32>cmd /c dir "C:\program files" /b`

Comment: Please show your attempt by editing-in the code section to your question. Why are you "forced" to use `cmd /c` and what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @magoo I'm forced because I'm executing it via Go

Comment: Possible alternatives:  a) Use https://godoc.org/io/ioutil#ReadDir to get a directory listing.  b) Invoke the command directly instead of running it in cmd.exe.

Comment: yes - seems to be a `go` problem rather than a `cmd` problem. Perhaps doubling up on the `"` in the value assigned to `cmd` (ie `cmd := `dir ""C:\Users\pyed\Desktop\new folder""``) - and that's a pure guess - I've no idea whatever about `go`. I thought it was a Chinese game...

Comment: @CodingPickle `dir` is part of `cmd` so it can't be Invoked directly, I've considered writing a lister using ReadDir, but I rather use `dir` with all its features instead.

Comment: @Magoo I added more quotes as you said just for fun, and I got a weird error: `The network name cannot be found.` ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 0):

so it is probably an `exec.Command` issue, doing the following works

```
command := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "dir", "C:\Users\pyed\Desktop\new folder")
```

and yes, you don't need to escape the space at all.